# How can I filter this data and return an array matching the condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tsx

This is the data I am working with below.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Frank Blanchard",
    gender: "male",
    friends: [
      {
        name: "Corina Irwin",
        gender: "female",
        sub_friends: [
          {
            name: "Alyssa Shelton",
            eyeColor: "brown",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Patrice Morton",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Hazel Berry",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Tricia Wells",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Mendoza Patton",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "male",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Jayne Boyd",
        gender: "female",
        sub_friends: [
          {
            name: "Jacobs Potter",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "male",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Justine Fox",
        gender: "female",
        sub_friends: [
          {
            name: "Madeline Harrell",
            eyeColor: "brown",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Simpson Pratt",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "male",
          },
          {
            name: "Rachel Mooney",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Ingrid Blackwell",
    gender: "female",
    friends: [
      {
        name: "Melody Carroll",
        gender: "female",
        sub_friends: [
          {
            name: "Sonja Gillespie",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Herring Kaufman",
        gender: "male",
        sub_friends: [
          {
            name: "Kathy Pennington",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Marisa Mckee",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Gillespie Dyer",
            eyeColor: "brown",
            gender: "male",
          },
          {
            name: "Aida Cantrell",
            eyeColor: "blue",
            gender: "female",
          },
          {
            name: "Lucy Mcconnell",
            eyeColor: "brown",
            gender: "female",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Isabelle Moon",
    gender: "female",
    friends: [
      {
        name: "Elnora Stone",
        gender: "female",
        sub_friends: [
          {
            name: "Collins Alford",
            eyeColor: "brown",
            gender: "male",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to go through to `sub_friends` and return all that match `gender === male`. My initial test was filtering to the `sub_friends`, which I then returned. But I am getting an empty array.

```
var filtered = data.filter(({ friends }) => {
    friends.filter(({ sub_friends }) => {
      return sub_friends.filter((element) => element.gender === "male");
    });
  });

console.log("LOG: ", filtered);
```

I also tried using `map`

```
var filtered = data.map(({ friends }) => {
    friends.map(({ sub_friends }) => {
      return sub_friends.filter((element) => element.gender === "male");
    });
  });

console.log("LOG: ", filtered);
```

I get

```
Array(3) [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

The output I want is an array, that I can map, to display the names in `sub_friends`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) together to achieve your goal.

*`flatMap` is to group all specific items into a new array.*

From your data, you have a list of `friends` and then find all `sub_friends` to put them under the same array. The last part is filtering all `info.gender === "male"` from `sub_friends`.

```js
//minified your data (not important)
const data=[{name:"Frank Blanchard",gender:"male",friends:[{name:"Corina Irwin",gender:"female",sub_friends:[{name:"Alyssa Shelton",eyeColor:"brown",gender:"female"},{name:"Patrice Morton",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"},{name:"Hazel Berry",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"},{name:"Tricia Wells",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"},{name:"Mendoza Patton",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"male"}]},{name:"Jayne Boyd",gender:"female",sub_friends:[{name:"Jacobs Potter",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"male"}]},{name:"Justine Fox",gender:"female",sub_friends:[{name:"Madeline Harrell",eyeColor:"brown",gender:"female"},{name:"Simpson Pratt",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"male"},{name:"Rachel Mooney",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"}]}]},{name:"Ingrid Blackwell",gender:"female",friends:[{name:"Melody Carroll",gender:"female",sub_friends:[{name:"Sonja Gillespie",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"}]},{name:"Herring Kaufman",gender:"male",sub_friends:[{name:"Kathy Pennington",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"},{name:"Marisa Mckee",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"},{name:"Gillespie Dyer",eyeColor:"brown",gender:"male"},{name:"Aida Cantrell",eyeColor:"blue",gender:"female"},{name:"Lucy Mcconnell",eyeColor:"brown",gender:"female"}]}]},{name:"Isabelle Moon",gender:"female",friends:[{name:"Elnora Stone",gender:"female",sub_friends:[{name:"Collins Alford",eyeColor:"brown",gender:"male"}]}]}];

//the main logic
const results = data.flatMap(info => info.friends).flatMap(info => info.sub_friends).filter(info => info.gender === "male")

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I think I should have maybe tried adding the `.filter()` after the previous one instead of inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function can help here (see the result image below).

The output can be further adjusted to store all the values in single array:

```js
let output = data.reduce(function(acc,curr) {
    let male = curr.friends.reduce(function(acc1,curr1) {
      acc1.push(curr1.sub_friends);
      return acc1;
    }, []);
    acc.push(male);
    return acc;
},[]);

let male = output.reduce(function(acc,curr) {
  let male1 = curr.reduce(function(acc1,curr1) {
    acc1.push(curr1.filter((x) => x.gender === "male"));
    return acc1;
  },[]);
  acc.push(male1);
  return acc;
},[])

console.log(male);
```

[image: result]

Comment: This looks like a longer approach compared to the first answer. But thanks for providing a different way.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and Specified method would be this approach which you can use forEach method and make a nested loop over the object of array and push sub_feriend name into arr and after that filter the array to get just the names

```
let arr = [];
data.forEach(({friends}) =>{
    friends.forEach(({sub_friends}) => {
        arr.push(sub_friends.find(x => x.gender === "male"))
    })
})

let names = arr.filter(x => x !== undefined).map(x => x.name)

console.log(names)
```